# How to login remotely to jenkins with user credentials?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, jenkins, jobs

currently i'm triggering several jobs with parameters, after a button is clicked on a .net website. The job is then started by an anonymous user.

This is the code for triggering the job:

```
protected void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string userName = txtUser.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;
        userName = Base64Util.Base64Encode(userName);
        password = Base64Util.Base64Encode(password);

        string url = Constants.build_jenkins_url + "/job/BUILD1/buildWithParameters?token=authtoken&Checkpoint=" + checkpointInput.Text + "&Git files=false" + "&SHA=None" + "&Build CST=true" + "&CST name=" + CSTNameInput.Text + "&Clean build=true" + "&Run sequences=false&user=" + userName + "&passwd=" + password;
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            Response.Redirect(Constants.build_jenkins_url, "_blank", "fullscreen=1,menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,titlebar=yes");

        }
```

I want to trigger the jobs with user credentials. In that case Jenkins will show me, who started the jenkins job. Do you guys have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

See information on [HttpWebRequest.Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Setting basic authentication, it will work:

```
URL urldemo = new URL(buildUrl);
URLConnection yc = urldemo.openConnection();
String userpass = userName + ":" + password;
String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());

yc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
```